# setwd() using GetActiveDocument() returns error - cannot change working directory

Tags: r, directory

I have the following code, which when trying to run it, gives an error stating that the work directory cannot be changed

```
src.path<-rstudioapi:::getActiveDocumentContext()$path
setwd(dirname(src.path))
```

Running `getwd()` provides the proper results. Checking `getActiveDocumentContext()$path` in the console yields simply `""`, which is probably the culprit for the error. My current working directory is my Documents. My source file is located here, so I can compile it just fine. However, I am trying to make a package, so I will need to get the user's working directory. What is causing `getActiveDocumentContext()` to fail?

Comment: Why do you need to get the user's working directory? What exactly are you trying to do? Are you trying to make a package that only works with rstudio and not R in general? Are you running this in the console or in an Rstudio editor? What output does `rstudioapi::getActiveDocumentContext()` return for you exactly?

Comment: @MrFlick I am ignorant on why. This is my professor's code, and he wanted me to put it in a package. From my knowledge, you need to have the proper working directory to run the source files, but I could be completely wrong.

Comment: That doesn't make much sense to me. Code in a package should never change a user's current working directory in my opinion. When making a package, all functions are merged into a namespace. You wouldn't use `source()` in that case at all. Have you seen the [R Packages book](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/)?

Comment: @MrFlick I have not. I will look into this, thank you!